# Que signifie « avoir un amour de petite moustache » ?

Tags: sens, expressions

Dans [*Premier Amour* de Tourgueniev](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premier_Amour_(Tourgueniev)), chapitre 9, la princesse Zinaïda et Vladimir Pétrovitch s'expriment :

> « Quel plaisir avez-vous à recevoir ce monsieur Malevsky ? lui
>   demandai-je un jour.
>
> — Oh ! il a un amour de petite moustache !
>   repliqua-t-elle. Et puis, à parler franc, vous n'y entendez rien. »

Que signifie, avoir un amour de petite moustache ? Je n'ai rien trouvé sur internet à propos de cette expression. Ainsi, ma première supposition, est que ce n'est pas une expression et qu'elle a simplement voulu dire qu'il a un amour de « quelqu'un qui a une petite moustache ». Cette supposition va avec sa moquerie d'après : « Et puis, à parler franc, vous n'y entendez rien ».

Sous entendu que sa moustache le rendrait inintelligible. Mais je ne suis pas sûr de ma supposition. Est-elle correcte ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Un amour de petite moustache* signifie *une délicieuse petite moustache*, *une adorable petite moustache*.

En anglais, on pourrait dire *a lovely little moustache*.

Il n'y a donc pas de lien avec *vous n'y entendez rien* qui signifie *vous ne comprenez rien à cela*.

Comment: Ohh ! J'avais mal compris, merci !